# Why can't I sort questions by "votes" or "unanswered" without logging in?

Tags: discussion, questions, login, unanswered-questions

On the "Questions" page of each Stack Exchange site, there are links at the top to sort the questions by "newest", "frequent", "votes", "active", and "unanswered".

At least that is what it looks like if I am logged in. If I am on a site that I don't have an account for, or if I am not logged in, the only one I see is "newest".

This seems to have been done recently. I could swear I saw the other links, even when I was not logged in, until a few weeks ago, or maybe later than that.

**Why was this change made?**

Comment: I actually just stumbled across this, and it surprised me, too. I'll look into what we did and why.

Answer (score 5):

Requests from anonymous users to some of these routes were causing an unacceptably large performance hit a few days ago, potentially hurting the experience for many other users.

As a result, they were disabled for anonymous users. They may be re-enabled at some point when we have had time to implement a less drastic solution, but for now removing them is necessary to ensure good performance for everyone.

#### Related:

- [Multiple tags with Java not working](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275311/multiple-tags-with-java-not-working)
- [Content does NOT change when changing tabs on /tagged for a particular tag when NOT logged in](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275326/content-does-not-change-when-changing-tabs-on-tagged-for-a-particular-tag-when)